# How to run multiple independent Loopback applications in a VPS server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback

If we have several mobile apps with different `Restful` web services based on `LoopBack` and `MongoDB`  how could we run these projects in same time in 
`VPS` to address `mobile apps` and `web apps` to connect and uses services.

**Update**

It is not important that all web services using one port its important that we can address them in different addressees something like:

```
http://82.25.14.23/App1/api/Rerification
http://82.25.14.23/testapp2/api/registration
http://82.25.14.23/PazarWebApp/api/catagories
```

Comment: different ports? reverse proxy? or another handful of approaches. It's an infrastructure question, not a programming one.

Comment: Hi @alex-blex, I dont have any Idea about how to do it but i remember in Oracle Appex It was manageable.

Comment: It is not that it is not manageable anywhere but in apex, it is just too vague. Too many possible solutions, all with its specific usecases. You need to narrow down the question, and ideally somewhere like on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: pretty easily. Run them, then proxy them together. just like anything else.

Comment: With the update, it seems nginx https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/ must be a good starting point.

Comment: Dear @AlexBlex thanks for your help. Is it part of Nginx Plus?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get plus what? It must be an nginx plus all your apps. Please read the docs behind the link. It describes how to proxy requests to the same server to different backends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As guys said this is mostly server related topic but waht you need to do is that :

> ```
> 1) each application should be run in different port number (3001, 3002, 3003)
> 2) map each address to a virtual server in appache or Nginx
> ```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName App1.yourdomain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001
    ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

So the app running at port 3001 will be mapped at App1.yourdomain.com

Subdomains are better than directory names.